# Show that $A∩B∩C= ∅$ is only true when $A∩B = ∅, A∩C = ∅$ or $B∩C = ∅$ or show a counterexample.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $A∩B∩C= ∅$ is only true when  $A∩B = ∅, A∩C = ∅$ or $B∩C = ∅$ or show a counterexample.

My answer:
True, Let set A={a,b,c,...}, set B={1,2,3,...} and set C={-1,-2,-3...}. Then there is not common elements in A, B or C. Thus, A∩B∩C= ∅. A∩B = ∅, A∩C = ∅ or B∩C = ∅.

Is my prove right?

Comment: It's not clear what the statement is. If it is “If $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\cap C=\emptyset$ and $B\cap C=\emptyset$”, then you can't prove it by example (and, by the way, it is false).

Comment: I believe you are confused about the question itself, which I believe to be the following: *Suppose $A, B, C$ are three sets, such that $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$. Is it true that $A \cap B = A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$?*

Comment: So, as advised also by @egreg, try to find three sets $A, B, C$ which satisfy $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$ but not (any of) the $A \cap B = A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$. You don't have to look far, you can choose $A, B, C \subset \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Comment: I edited your question (partially); check it please

Comment: As a general comment, remember that if you want to prove a given property you must do that formally not by an example. You provide an example where the statement hold. This does not imply that the statement is always true ($A=B=$non empty, $C=\emptyset$). On the other hand it suffices only one counterexample to show that the statement does not always hold.

Comment: did you mean **or** - the proof is more complicated

Comment: @ Jon Mark Perry , oh yes, my mistake. its suppose to be oA∩B∩C= ∅. A∩B = ∅, A∩C = ∅ OR B∩C = ∅.

Comment: bit late for that now - try another posting :))

Comment: No, probably better to fix this posted question, otherwise it would look like an attempt to make a duplicate of one's own question when people complain about the first question. That is seen as an attempt to circumvent the system.

Comment: @user1 has probably given a perfect answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\{1,2\}, B=\{2,3,4,5\}, C=\{1,5\}$$ then:
A∩B∩C= ∅
A∩B={2}
A∩C= {1}
B∩C= {5}

Comment: It is the perfect answer, I think...

Answer (score 6):

(Just another counterexample.)

[image: Yet another counterexample]

Answer (score 5):

Hint: consider $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$ and $C=\{1,3\}$.

---

When you have a statement of the form

> If $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\cap C=\emptyset$ and $B\cap C=\emptyset$

you can't prove it *true* by example. You can prove it *false* by showing a counterexample.