# A∩B∩C=∅, then A∩B=∅,A∩C=∅ or B∩C=∅

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sorry everyone, I made a mistake in my question itself for my previous posting:
[Show that $A∩B∩C= ∅$ is only true when $A∩B = ∅, A∩C = ∅$ or $B∩C = ∅$ or show a counterexample.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234178/a%E2%88%A9b%E2%88%A9c-%E2%88%85-a%E2%88%A9b-%E2%88%85-a%E2%88%A9c-%E2%88%85-or-b%E2%88%A9c-%E2%88%85?noredirect=1#comment2509682_1234178)

It should have been:

If A∩B∩C=∅, then A∩B=∅,A∩C=∅ or B∩C=∅. Prove **or** show counterexample.

So false, if I take A={1,2}, B={2,3}, and C={1,3}. then A∩B∩C=∅, but A∩B={2},A∩C={1},B∩C={3}. Thus leads to contradiction. Is this correct?

By the way, can someone explain to me the difference in the prove when the question is **or** and **and**.

Comment: You can edit your previous question. Actually, I did it for you.

Comment: Your proof is okay.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Editing like that is in my view not the right thing to do here. All answers given to the original question (asked before the edit) are somehow made irrelevant now. I request you to withdraw your edit.

Comment: @drhab Ok. I'm sorry, I thought it was right. I'll do it right now.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Ego te absolvo. Btw, it is nice that the OP refers in this question to his former question. That prevents that it will be treated as a duplicate and gives useful information.

Comment: Peter created a new question instead of editing and fixing the mistake of the old question. The old question has been edited and is now correct, so this question is now effectively a duplicate.